# Can i set boundaries for the JProgressBar in a GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, progress-bar, gridbaglayout

I use a ProgressBar within a GridBagLayout. Outside of the Layout, setting the boundaries works perfectly. Within the GridBagLayout i can't adjust them in any way. What can i do?

```
base[i] = new JPanel();
base[i].setLayout(gbl);
progressBar[i] = new JProgressBar();
progressBar[i].setForeground(Color.GREEN);
progressBar[i].setValue(s1.getInBesitz().get(i).getAktKp() * 100 / s1.getInBesitz().get(i).getMaxKp());
progressBar[i].setBounds(110, 280, 180, 5);
if (progressBar[i].getValue() < 50) {
    progressBar[i].setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    if (progressBar[i].getValue() < 25) {
        progressBar[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
    }
}
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 5;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
base[i].add(progressBar[i], gbc);
```

Comment: if you are using a `LayoutManager` (e.g. `GridBagLayout`) it will set the bounds, In that case you must adjust the constraint (e.g. `GridBagConstraint`) to instruct the manager how to lay out the components. You could eventually set the `Insets`, padding, anchor,... [documentaiton](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) (kind o hard to say wihtout knowing what you wnat to accomplish)

Comment: I want to make the progressBar thinner, ipady helps me but also overlaps other components with white space.. maybe i can make it transparent?

Comment: ok i solved it. the ipady was counting for every component, i didnt know^^ I now addes a new constraint only for the progressBar